# Xamarin.Forms (Read file from platform project in PCL code)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am building a Xamarin.Forms project with a PCL, iOS and Android project. One of my requirements is that I have to read a JSON file stored in the platform project (iOS/Android) from the PCL.

How can I do this please? I can't find a solution for this problem. :(

Thank you very much,
Nikolai

Answer (score 2):

If the file that you want to read is embedded in the platform project assembly you can use the following code:

```
var assembly = typeof(MyPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream)) {
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Make sure that you replace WorkingWithFiles with namespace of your project and PCLTextResource.txt with name of the file.

Check Xamarin documentation at [Loading Files Embedded as Resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources) for more details

If on the other hand you want to create and read/write files at runtime you can use [PCLStorage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/pclstorage) library:

```
public async Task PCLStorageSample()
{
    IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("answer.txt",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync("42");
}
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi, I have tried the above. Unfortunately is doesn't work. The code above only works if the file is an embedded resource in the PCL, correct? I on the other hand want to read a file that is stored in the iOS project in PCL code. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user2118781: Can you embed the file in PCL?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using an IoC container.

In my iOS project I have created a ConfigAccess class:

```
public class ConfigAccess : IConfigAccess
{
    public string ReadConfigAsString()
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText("config.json");
    }
}
```

I also had to add the following line to my AppDelegate.cs

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IConfigAccess, ConfigAccess>();
```

And in my PCL I am simply asking for a ConfigAccess object during runtime:

```
var configAccess = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IConfigAccess>();
var test = configAccess.ReadConfigAsString();
```